# Trouble Texturing VBO

Tags: c#, opengl, vbo, texture-mapping, opentk

It seems as though I am having some trouble with texturing VBOs in my game. The VBO itself, seems to render just fine, and I can even toggle the faces away accordingly. However, when I try to add textures everything looks skewed and some textures are even on the wrong face. Everything was working fine when I was using VAO's, so I am currently at a loss as to why the textures suddenly are not working.

Here is an image:

[image]

And here is the associated data:

```
private static uint frontFaceHandle;
        private static uint backFaceHandle;
        private static uint leftFaceHandle;
        private static uint rightFaceHandle;
        private static uint topFaceHandle;
        private static uint bottomFaceHandle;


        private static uint indexBufferId;
        private static uint colorBufferId;
        private static uint texCoordBufferId;

        private static float[] textureCoordData = {
            0, 1,
            1, 1,
            1, 0,
            0, 0,
        };

        private static ushort[] indices = {
            0, 1, 3,
            0, 3, 2
        };

        private static float[] colorData = {
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        };

        private static float[] frontFaceVert = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
        };

        private static float[] backFaceVert = {
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
        };

        private static float[] leftFaceVert = {
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
        };

        private static float[] rightFaceVert = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        };

        private static float[] topFaceVert = {
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,
        };

        private static float[] bottomFaceVert = {
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        };
```

The Way I upload the data:

```
static Voxel() {
            /**
             * Front Face
             */
            GL.GenBuffers( 1 , out frontFaceHandle );
            GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , frontFaceHandle );
            GL.BufferData(
                BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer ,
                ( IntPtr )( frontFaceVert.Length * sizeof( float ) ) ,
                frontFaceVert ,
                BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
            /**
             * Back Face
             */
            GL.GenBuffers( 1 , out backFaceHandle );
            GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , backFaceHandle );
            GL.BufferData(
                BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer ,
                ( IntPtr )( backFaceVert.Length * sizeof( float ) ) ,
                backFaceVert ,
                BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
            /**
             * Left Face
             */
            GL.GenBuffers( 1 , out leftFaceHandle );
            GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , leftFaceHandle );
            GL.BufferData(
                BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer ,
                ( IntPtr )( leftFaceVert.Length * sizeof( float ) ) ,
                leftFaceVert ,
                BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
            /**
             * Right Face
             */
            GL.GenBuffers( 1 , out rightFaceHandle );
            GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , rightFaceHandle );
            GL.BufferData(
                BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer ,
                ( IntPtr )( rightFaceVert.Length * sizeof( float ) ) ,
                rightFaceVert ,
                BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
            /**
             * Top Face
             */
            GL.GenBuffers( 1 , out topFaceHandle );
            GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , topFaceHandle );
            GL.BufferData(
                BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer ,
                ( IntPtr )( topFaceVert.Length * sizeof( float ) ) ,
                topFaceVert ,
                BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
            /**
             * Bottom Face
             */
            GL.GenBuffers( 1 , out bottomFaceHandle );
            GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , bottomFaceHandle );
            GL.BufferData(
                BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer ,
                ( IntPtr )( bottomFaceVert.Length * sizeof( float ) ) ,
                bottomFaceVert ,
                BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
            /**
             * Texture Buffer
             */
            GL.GenBuffers( 1 , out texCoordBufferId );
            GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , texCoordBufferId );
            GL.BufferData( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , ( IntPtr )( textureCoordData.Length * sizeof( float ) ) , textureCoordData , BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );

            /**
             * Index Buffer
             */
            GL.GenBuffers( 1 , out indexBufferId );
            GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer , indexBufferId );
            GL.BufferData(
                BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer ,
                ( IntPtr )( indices.Length * sizeof( ushort ) ) ,
                indices ,
                BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
            /**
             * Color buffer (This Remains unused for now
             */
            GL.GenBuffers( 1 , out colorBufferId );
            GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , colorBufferId );
            GL.BufferData(
                BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer ,
                ( IntPtr )colorData.Length ,
                colorData ,
                BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw );
        }
```

And the way I draw the cube (Each face is a seperate vbo):

```
public void Render( FirstPersonCameraWidget gameCamera ) {
            GL.Translate( Location.X , Location.Y , Location.Z );
            GL.Enable( EnableCap.Texture2D );
            GL.EnableClientState( ArrayCap.VertexArray );
            GL.EnableClientState( ArrayCap.TextureCoordArray );
            if( ShowFrontFace ) {

                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , frontFaceHandle );
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.TextureBuffer , texCoordBufferId );
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer , indexBufferId );
                GL.VertexPointer( 3 , VertexPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );
                GL.TexCoordPointer( 2 , TexCoordPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );
                GL.BindTexture( TextureTarget.Texture2D , TextureAtlas.FrontFace.GetID() );
                GL.DrawElements( PrimitiveType.Triangles , 6 , DrawElementsType.UnsignedShort , IntPtr.Zero );
            }
            if( ShowBackFace ) {
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , backFaceHandle );
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.TextureBuffer , texCoordBufferId );
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer , indexBufferId );
                GL.VertexPointer( 3 , VertexPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );
                GL.TexCoordPointer( 2 , TexCoordPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );
                GL.BindTexture( TextureTarget.Texture2D , TextureAtlas.BackFace.GetID() );
                GL.DrawElements( PrimitiveType.Triangles , 6 , DrawElementsType.UnsignedShort , IntPtr.Zero );
            }
            if( ShowLeftFace ) {
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , leftFaceHandle );
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.TextureBuffer , texCoordBufferId );
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer , indexBufferId );
                GL.VertexPointer( 3 , VertexPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );
                GL.TexCoordPointer( 2 , TexCoordPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );
                GL.BindTexture( TextureTarget.Texture2D , TextureAtlas.LeftFace.GetID() );
                GL.DrawElements( PrimitiveType.Triangles , 6 , DrawElementsType.UnsignedShort , IntPtr.Zero );
            }
            if( ShowRightFace ) {
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , rightFaceHandle );
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.TextureBuffer , texCoordBufferId );
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer , indexBufferId );
                GL.VertexPointer( 3 , VertexPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );
                GL.TexCoordPointer( 2 , TexCoordPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );
                GL.BindTexture( TextureTarget.Texture2D , TextureAtlas.RightFace.GetID() );
                GL.DrawElements( PrimitiveType.Triangles , 6 , DrawElementsType.UnsignedShort , IntPtr.Zero );
            }
            if( ShowTopFace ) {
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , topFaceHandle );
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.TextureBuffer , texCoordBufferId );
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer , indexBufferId );
                GL.VertexPointer( 3 , VertexPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );
                GL.TexCoordPointer( 2 , TexCoordPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );
                GL.BindTexture( TextureTarget.Texture2D , TextureAtlas.TopFace.GetID() );
                GL.DrawElements( PrimitiveType.Triangles , 6 , DrawElementsType.UnsignedShort , IntPtr.Zero );
            }
            if( ShowBottomFace ) {
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , bottomFaceHandle );
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.TextureBuffer , texCoordBufferId );
                GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer , indexBufferId );
                GL.VertexPointer( 3 , VertexPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );
                GL.TexCoordPointer( 2 , TexCoordPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );
                GL.BindTexture( TextureTarget.Texture2D , TextureAtlas.BottomFace.GetID() );
                GL.DrawElements( PrimitiveType.Triangles , 6 , DrawElementsType.UnsignedShort , IntPtr.Zero );
            }
            GL.Translate( -Location.X , -Location.Y , -Location.Z );
        }
```

Hoping someone can spot what I did wrong.

Update: I have fixed the code given the suggestion of @Andom M. Coleman and it worked, however the cube is still *slightly* skewed.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using different VBOs for your texture coordinate array and position array, correct? There are not discrete binding locations for those things, your code should actually look like this:

```
        if( ShowFrontFace ) {
            GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , frontFaceHandle );
            GL.VertexPointer( 3 , VertexPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );

            // ArrayBuffer!
            GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , texCoordBufferId ); 
            GL.TexCoordPointer( 2 , TexCoordPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );

            GL.BindTexture( TextureTarget.Texture2D , TextureAtlas.FrontFace.GetID() );

            GL.BindBuffer( BufferTarget.ElementArrayBuffer , indexBufferId );
            GL.DrawElements( PrimitiveType.Triangles , 6 , DrawElementsType.UnsignedShort , IntPtr.Zero );
```

*<sub>**NOTE:** `BufferTarget.TextureBuffer` is actually for a completely different use of buffer objects (Texture Buffer Objects).</sub>*

For vertex buffers, you will always bind them to `BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer` and then the next `gl___CoordPointer (...)` call will be relative to whatever is currently bound there.

In your original code, since `BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer` was only being set once, your texture coordinate pointer was actually coming from the same set of data as your vertex positions. That is obviously not the behavior you want.

---

In fact, if you want to get fancy, you can pull the specification of the texture pointer out of the branch because it is invariant. Just do the following ***once*** each time you draw your cube:

```
            GL.BindBuffer     ( BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer , texCoordBufferId     ); 
            GL.TexCoordPointer( 2 , TexCoordPointerType.Float , 0 , IntPtr.Zero );
```

Comment: I will most certainly do that, however, do you know why my textures are still slightly skewed? Is it my Texture coordinates?

Comment: Yes, judging from the way your vertex positions are set up, I think your coordinates should actually be: 0,0  0,1  1,0  1,1.

Comment: Those coordinates flipped everything onto it's side, but at least now I know that it is the texture coordinates. Thank you for your help; accepting as answer now.

Comment: the correct texture coordinates were: private static float[] textureCoordData = {
            0, 1,
            1, 1,
            0, 0,
            1, 0
        };